# Can i check if any F-Key is pressed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, scene

Ok I want to check if any of the f keys are pressed:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F1)||
    Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F2)||
    Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F3)||
    Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F4)||
    ...){}
```

this seems very uneffective.

So i basically switch my Scenes when pressing f1, f2 etc. and i want to save the varibales to a global object when i'm leaving a scene.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a better way than what you're already doing, but what do you mean by "I want to save the varibales to a global object"? Is that just the code you want to run when the function keys are pressed?

Comment: Have you found any use for the Input manager and creating multiple input axes for "F-Keys"? You can create multiple "SwitchScene" axes under the input manager, each with 2 buttons (positive and alt positive) for one of the F keys. Then you can simply listen to Input.GetButtonDown("SwitchScene")

Comment: @Draco18s I learned in a video, that i could save some variables like ints and strings on a Global Object and load them in another scene. I want to save the values when I am leaving the scene, so i need my script to react when I'm switching a scene

Comment: @ErikOverflow Thanks for the answer and i guess that helps. I think there is just no "real" way to do this?

Comment: You can save any data you want anywhere you want however you want. Its just a matter of picking a location that persists between scenes, such as a static class. You aren't limited to ints and strings.

Comment: @CherryFake if this is your actual goal then why not simply let it do that in `OnDestroy` which gets called when the scene is unloaded due to a "switch"?

Comment: I think i didn't really write what i wanted to say. everything is working. I just wanted to ask for a smarter way of checking if any f-key is pressed - and it seems that there is none. but thanks everyone for wanting to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way your checking is alright.

But global variable? I think you mean a Variable you can access from anywhere.

Data persistence  between scene's can be done in so many different way's I'll try to give u a Example

So lets say your on Scene 1. You have a High Score you want to save. Static variables are great for Unity passthrews Imo atleast

```
    public class Score
    {
        public static int Highscore;
    }



    class Scene1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F1)||
               Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F2)||
               Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F3)||
               Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F4)||
                 ...){
                       Score.Highscore = 5;
                       Console.WriteLine("Highscore: " +  Score.Highscore);
                       SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
                     }
    //Output is = 5
        }
    }
```

````
class Scene2
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Highscore: " +  Score.Highscore);
           //Output will still be 5
        }
    }
    ```
````